# C++ Memory Segmentation Fault?

Tags: python, c++, csv, c++11

I wrote a program that fetches stock data from google finance and performs buy/sell decision. I wrote it in Visual Studio C++ and it works fine on Windows, but when I try to compile it on ubautu with `g++ -std=c++11 stock.cpp` and I run the a.out I get a seg fault. Where am I going wrong?

From main(), error occurs on second call to SMA():

```
            decisionPoint_model_call(); 
            //this function call a function called SMA() twice to calculate two different moving averages
            //the second time SMA() is called from inside decisionPoint_model_call() a seg. fault occurs
```

gdb gave me the following error:

> 0xb7f42ac5 in std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<< , std::allocator >(std::basic_ostream >&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

The code is as follows:

**stock.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>


using namespace std;

int numberOfDays; //total number of days
int dayNumber = 0; //0 being the starting date

struct each_day {
    string date;
    float open;
    float high;
    float low;
    float close;
    float volume;
    float mov_avg[1];

};

each_day *day = nullptr;

//store parced cotents in structure one day at a time
void float2structure(string date, float open, float high, float low, float close, float volume)
{
    if (dayNumber == 0)
    {
        day = new each_day[numberOfDays];
    }

    day[dayNumber].date = date;
    day[dayNumber].open = open;
    day[dayNumber].high = high;
    day[dayNumber].low = low;
    day[dayNumber].close = close;
    day[dayNumber].volume = volume;

    if (dayNumber != numberOfDays)
    {
        dayNumber++;
    }



}

void line2float(string line_string) //reads line and converts appropriate type
{

    string date;
    float open;
    float high;
    float low;
    float close;
    float volume;

    string temp;

    int dataBlocks = 1;

    istringstream ss(line_string);
    while (!ss.eof())
    {
        switch (dataBlocks)
        {
        case 1:
            getline(ss, date, ',');
        case 2:
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            if (temp == "-") {
                temp = "0";
            }
            open = stof(temp);
        case 3:
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            if (temp == "-") {
                temp = "0";
            }
            high = stof(temp);
        case 4:
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            if (temp == "-") {
                temp = "0";
            }
            low = stof(temp);
        case 5:
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            if (temp == "-") {
                temp = "0";
            }
            close = stof(temp);
        case 6:
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            if (temp == "-") {
                temp = "0";
            }
            volume = stof(temp);
        }

    }
    float2structure(date, open, high, low, close, volume);
}

//gets line, sort in correct order, send each line to next function 
void lineGet(ifstream &inFile) 
{
    cout << "Reorganizing data... be patient..." << endl;

    vector<string> lines_in_reverse;
    string line;
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        // Store the lines in reverse order.
        lines_in_reverse.insert(lines_in_reverse.begin(), line);

    }

    numberOfDays = lines_in_reverse.size() - 1;  

    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfDays; x++)
    {
        line2float(lines_in_reverse[x]);
    }


}

//calculed the SMA and stores that in data.mov_avg[x]
void SMA(int movingAvg, int mv_num)
{
    deque <float> sma;
    float smaSize = (float)movingAvg;

    float sum_of_elems = 0;

    for (dayNumber = 0; dayNumber < numberOfDays; dayNumber++)
    {
        cout << day[dayNumber].date << " " <<dayNumber<<endl;

        if (dayNumber <= smaSize - 1)
        {

            sma.push_front(day[dayNumber].close);

            day[dayNumber].mov_avg[mv_num] = 0; //ERROR HERE?


            if (dayNumber == smaSize - 1)
            {
                for (float n : sma) {
                    sum_of_elems += n;
                }

                day[dayNumber].mov_avg[mv_num] = sum_of_elems / smaSize;

            }


        }
        else
        {
            sum_of_elems = 0;
            sma.pop_back();
            sma.push_front(day[dayNumber].close);

            for (float n : sma)
            {
                sum_of_elems += n;
            }

            day[dayNumber].mov_avg[mv_num] = sum_of_elems / smaSize;

        }

    }

}

//function to analyze data and report trades
void decisionPoint_model(string startDate)
{
    dayNumber = 0;
    bool holdingLong = false;
    bool shortSell = false;
    float totalProfit = 0;
    float buyPrice;
    float sellPrice;
    float shortPrice;
    float coverPrice;

    //loop though each day, compare moving averages, buy and sell based on moving averages
    for (; dayNumber < numberOfDays; dayNumber++) {
        //cout << day[dayNumber].moving_avg[0] << " " << day[dayNumber].moving_avg[1] << endl;
        if (day[dayNumber].mov_avg[1] != 0) {

            if (day[dayNumber].mov_avg[0] < day[dayNumber].mov_avg[1] && holdingLong == true) {
                //sell
                sellPrice = day[dayNumber + 1].open;
                totalProfit += (sellPrice - buyPrice);
                cout << "Sell: $" << day[dayNumber + 1].open << " on " << day[dayNumber + 1].date << endl;
                cout << "Profit from trade: $" << sellPrice - buyPrice << endl;
                cout << "Total profit: $" << totalProfit << endl;
                cout << endl;
                holdingLong = false;
            }
            if (day[dayNumber].mov_avg[0] < day[dayNumber].mov_avg[1] && shortSell == false) {
                //short
                shortPrice = day[dayNumber + 1].open;
                cout << "Short: $" << day[dayNumber + 1].open << " on " << day[dayNumber + 1].date << ", ";
                shortSell = true;
            }
            if (day[dayNumber].mov_avg[0] > day[dayNumber].mov_avg[1] && shortSell == true) {
                //cover
                coverPrice = day[dayNumber + 1].open;
                totalProfit += (shortPrice - coverPrice);
                cout << "Cover: $" << day[dayNumber + 1].open << " on " << day[dayNumber + 1].date << endl;
                cout << "Profit from trade: $" << shortPrice - coverPrice << endl;
                cout << "Total profit: $" << totalProfit << endl;
                cout << endl;
                shortSell = false;
            }
            if (day[dayNumber].mov_avg[0] > day[dayNumber].mov_avg[1] && holdingLong == false) {
                //buy
                buyPrice = day[dayNumber + 1].open;
                cout << "Buy: $" << day[dayNumber + 1].open << " on " << day[dayNumber + 1].date << ", ";
                holdingLong = true;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total profits from strategy: $" << totalProfit << endl;
    cout << endl;
}


void decisionPoint_model_call() {


    cout << "testing end" << endl;
    cout << "\nWe are going to perfrom a decision point analysis." << endl;
    cout << "This requires two moving averages relatively close by (eg. 10 and 15 day moving averages)." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    int movingavg;
    cout << "Set the first moving average (ex. 10):";
    cin >> movingavg;
    SMA(movingavg, 0);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Set the second moving average (ex. 15):";
    cin >> movingavg;
    SMA(movingavg, 1); //ERROR OCCURS THE SECOND TIME WE CALL SMA() 



    cout << "\nData stretches from: " << day[0].date << " to " << day[numberOfDays - 1].date << endl;
    cout << "NO ERROR" << endl;
    string startDate;
    cout << "Enter a date to begin analysis: ";
    cin >> startDate;
    cout << endl;

    decisionPoint_model(startDate);
    cout << "Open price on first day (given data): $" << day[0].open << endl;
    cout << "Close price on last day (given data): $" << day[numberOfDays - 1].close << endl;
    cout << "For a total price change of: $" << day[numberOfDays - 1].close - day[0].open << endl;
    cout << endl;

}
void file_get() {


functionStart:
    string filename;
    cout << "\nEnter file name (ex. goog.csv):";
    cin >> filename;

    ifstream inFile(filename.c_str());
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "\nLoading file...\n" << endl;
        lineGet(inFile);
        inFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "No file was found on disk, retrieving one from the web..." << endl;
        system("python stockFetch.py");
        goto functionStart;
    }
}



int main()
{

    cout << endl;
    cout << "What type on analysis would you like to perform?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Decision Point Analysis - based on historical data." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter number: "; //only number that works is 1 currently
    int analysisNumber;
    cin >> analysisNumber;

    switch (analysisNumber) {
    case 1:
        file_get(); 
            //order of calls: 1.file_get() -> 2.lineGet() -> 3.line2float() -> 4.float2structure()
            //function 2 - 4 are called over and over again to store each line from the cvs file to the structure

        decisionPoint_model_call(); 
            //this function call function called SMA() twice to calculate two different moving averages
            //the second time SMA() is called from inside decisionPoint_model_call() a seg. fault occurs



    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

To get stock data file, you need to get the csv file from [here](http://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=22144&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2001&enddate=Mar+21%2C+2016&num=30&ei=77jvVpmqGYSA2AaLz7vwCA&output=csv) save this as `aapl.csv`.

Or save the following python file, as the c++ program makes a call to it if it can't find a .csv file on disk.

**stockFetch.py**

```
import sys, os, urllib

#get the csv file from google finance
tickerSymbol= raw_input('Enter the ticker symbol: ')
startDate = raw_input('Enter the start date(Ex. Jan 20, 2015): ')
endDate = raw_input('Enter the end date: ')
startDate.replace (" ", "+")
startDate.replace (",", "2C")
endDate.replace (" ", "+")
endDate.replace (",", "2C")

url = "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q="+str(tickerSymbol)+"&startdate="+str(startDate)+"&enddate="+str(endDate)+"&output=csv"


urllib.urlretrieve(url, str(tickerSymbol))
if os.path.isfile(str(tickerSymbol)):
       os.rename(str(tickerSymbol), str(tickerSymbol)+".csv")
       print ("--File Fetched--")
       sys.exit()

print ("--Could not find file--")
```

Comment: Please post [mcve]. Keyword - minimal.

Comment: Or use a debugger.  You need to at least use basic debugging skills to find where the crash is happening, and then ask a question if you don't understand why.  Chances are you are making assumptions about the size of your vectors and strings, or doing bad stuff like subtracting 1 from an unsigned value that is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the only error, but is an error.

You define `each_day::mov_avg` of size 1

```
float mov_avg[1];
```

but is used in position 2

```
day[dayNumber].mov_avg[mv_num] = 0; //ERROR HERE? (yes, when mv_num == 1)
[...]
day[dayNumber].mov_avg[mv_num] = sum_of_elems / smaSize;
[...]
day[dayNumber].mov_avg[mv_num] = sum_of_elems / smaSize;
[...]
if (day[dayNumber].mov_avg[1] != 0) {
    if (day[dayNumber].mov_avg[0] < day[dayNumber].mov_avg[1] && holdingLong == true) {
[...]
```

Try defining

```
float mov_avg[2];
```